# URI is not registered after pulling Github project in android studio

Tags: android, github

I pulled the following project into my android studio, but the following link in manifest is shown in red and I got this error message: URI is not registered.
here is the code of my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.caldroid"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Answer (score -1):

Role of android manifest has now been distributed with gradle. 
When you imported the project, only import build.gradle and it will automatically determine the folder structure and android manifest as well.

Comment: Thank you dear, but I did not get your point as I just done clone URL and imported the entire file from github. So, shall I add each file manually or what? show me your way please!